# "Tab" in the middle of line. Indent instead of making a tab. (VS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, indentation, tabs

I think the headline says it all. But when I'm hitting the tab button in the middle of a line of code I want it to indent the whole line instead of making a tab which is not very useful - I never use tab in the code besides indenting and if I have to use a tab in a string I use `\t`. I know it´s only saving me two buttons each time (one on US keyboards, I guess) but it would definitely be nice to have.

I have looked for this in extensions "PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010" and "Productivity tools" but haven't found what I looked for. So, do anyone know whether there is a feature or extension I haven't found? Otherwise, I guess I have to do it myself ;-)

I work primarily with C#, F# and Asp.Net (html etc.) so it would be nice to have it work with these, but of cause broader solutions is better (and ex a C# only solution would also be nice).

Comment: You can do it with a macro.  You'll love the balloon.

Comment: Nice, VS 2010 crashes when I try to do record one ;)

Comment: If you aren't able to get it working with a macro, send me an email (noahric @ ms) and I can help you write an extension to do this.  I'm guess you may have to, anyway, if your intent is that the caret doesn't visibly move due to the indent (besides the text normally sliding over).

Comment: @Noah Cool, but I feel I should try to build one on my own before asking for help to do it. So I'll try to build one upon a sample extension. But I might contact you if I fail :-) thanks...

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in VS2010 called "Automatic Indentation On Tab" that does exactly that.  It is found under Tools>Options>Text Editor>C/C++>Formatting.
Obviously that seems to be only for C++ and that is not what you want.  But if you can live without the other C# specific editing tools, you could tell VS that your files are C/C++ type files (Tools>Options>Text Editor>File Extension).

Comment: Cool, but I don't think I can live without the C# specifics but thanks :)